# How to create the XML file by means of LINQ and a cycle on a certain condition?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a List itms of the following class:

```
public class Itm
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string PAR1{ get; set; }
       public string PAR2{ get; set; }           
       ...
       public string PAR7{ get; set; }
   }
```

It is necessary to create the XML file of the following look:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfItms xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Itm>
    <TYPE>
      <PAR1>value</PAR1>
      <PAR2>value</PAR2>
    </TYPE>
    <NMB>
      <PAR3>value</PAR4>
      <PAR4>value</PAR4>     
    </NMB>
    <ArrOfPR>
      <TPR>
        <PAR5>value</PAR5>
        <PAR6>value</PAR6>
      </TPR>          
    </ArrOfPR>
</Itm>
</ArrayOfItms>
```

The problem is that if PAR5 and PAR6 comprise a comma, then it is necessary to divide these values in separate tags `<TPR>`.

For example:

```
itms.PAR5 is equal to 43232,62695
itms.PAR6 is equal to Kursk, Soligorsk
```

Means in the XML file has to be so:

```
<ArrOfPR>
      <TPR>
        <PAR5>43232</PAR5>
        <PAR6>Kursk</PAR6>
      </TPR>    
      <TPR>
        <PAR5>62695</PAR5>
        <PAR6>Soligorsk</PAR6>
      </TPR>        
    </ArrOfPR>
```

How to use in this situation loops and conditional operators(if..then)? Thanks.

**EDIT.** Answer for comments:

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
            new XElement("ArrayOfItms",
                             new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
                             new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")));
    foreach (Itm itm in itms)
    {
        xdoc.Root.Add(new XElement("Itm",
            new XElement("TYPE", new XElement("PAR1", itm.PAR1), new XElement("PAR2", itm.PAR2)),
            new XElement("NMB", new XElement("PAR3", itm.PAR3), new XElement("PAR4", itm.PAR4)),
            new XElement("ArrOfPR",
```

I can't insert such code (sorry for pseudo-code) further:

```
if (itm.PAR5.Contains(','))
  int indexZap = itm.PAR5.IndexOf(',');
   string firstO = itm.PAR5.Substring(0, indexZap);
   string secondO = itm.PAR5.Substring(indexZap + 2);

   int indexZap2 = itm.PAR6.IndexOf(',');
   string firstG = itm.PAR6.Substring(0, indexZap);
   string secondG = itm.PAR6.Substring(indexZap + 2);

   xdoc.Add(new XElement("TPR"));
   xdoc.Add(new XElement("PAR5", firstG));
   xdoc.Add(new XElement("PAR6", firstO));
   xdoc.Add(new XElement("TPR"));
   xdoc.Add(new XElement("PAR5", secondG));
   xdoc.Add(new XElement("PAR6", secondO));
```

Comment: Please show your work.

Comment: Just edited, see please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve you problem with the Linq `Zip` function - it's join two sequences by index. This means that you need to split your cities list in the `PAR5` and then zip that list with splitted values from a `PAR6` property

For **input**

```
var itms = new []
{
    new Itm
    {
        PAR1 = "value for Par1",
        PAR2 = "value for Par2",
        PAR3 = "value for Par3",
        PAR4 = "value for Par4",
        PAR5 = "43232,62695",
        PAR6 = "Kursk, Soligorsk",
    },
};
```

you can apply this linq query

```
var xItems = itms.Select(x => new XElement("Itm",
    new XElement("TYPE",
        new XElement("PAR1", x.PAR1),
        new XElement("PAR2", x.PAR2)
    ),
    new XElement("NMB",
        new XElement("PAR3", x.PAR3),
        new XElement("PAR4", x.PAR4)
    ),
    new XElement("ArrOfPR",
        x.PAR5.Split(',').Zip(x.PAR6.Split(','), (p5, p6) => new
            XElement("TPR",
                new XElement("PAR5", p5),
                new XElement("PAR6", p6)
            ))
    )
  ));
```

now you can assemble all XDocument

```
var arrayOfItems = new XElement("ArrayOfItms",
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"));
arrayOfItems.Add(xItems);

var xdoc = new XDocument(arrayOfItems);
```

**Result** is:

```
<ArrayOfItms xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Itm>
    <TYPE>
      <PAR1>value for Par1</PAR1>
      <PAR2>value for Par2</PAR2>
    </TYPE>
    <NMB>
      <PAR3>value for Par3</PAR3>
      <PAR4>value for Par4</PAR4>
    </NMB>
    <ArrOfPR>
      <TPR>
        <PAR5>43232</PAR5>
        <PAR6>Kursk</PAR6>
      </TPR>
      <TPR>
        <PAR5>62695</PAR5>
        <PAR6> Soligorsk</PAR6>
      </TPR>
    </ArrOfPR>
  </Itm>
</ArrayOfItms>
```

Note: to avoid extra space for Soligorsk, you can use `Split` with `Trim`

Comment: can you explain, how to cut string "key:value; key:value; key:value" into that xml like previous <ArrOfPR> <TPR> <PAR5> <PAR6>, but <ArrofPar> <PAR> <KEY><VALUE>? I'm trying to do like you show but catch  an exception.

Comment: @feofan It's look like you need to split by `;` then by `:`. It would be better if you create a new question and put your actual input, code you have and exception you get into it.

Comment: The error arose because the last element of the formed array for some reason was empty. The array is then formed without errors: `x.PAR.Split(';').Select(a => a.Split(':')).Take(x.PAR.Split(';').Select(a => a.Split(':')).Count() - 1).ToArray()`, but have not idea how to add keys and values in xml tags.

Comment: Sorry, it was so easy :`x.PAR.Split(';').Select(a => a.Split(':')).Take(x.PAR.Split(';').Select(a => a.Split(':')).Count() - 1).ToArray().Select( a =>  
          new XElement("PAR",                  
                              new XElement("KEY", a[0]),
                          new XElement("VALUE", a[1])
                          )`